# Is it possible to stop output to console within eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, testng

within eclipse running same result will be output console and testng plugin view.most of time,I will switch back to testng plugin view to check result.so is it possible to stop to output running result to eclipse console view?Or let user to choose which view be current view(or called default result checking view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but you can [disable automatic showing](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/console/ref-console_view.htm) of the console view by unchecking icons [image: Show Console When Standard Out Changes] and [image: Show Console When Standard Error Changes].

Alternatively you can discard all your output just by redirecting it to a `/dev/null` (if you are on UNIX based system) in *Run Configurations > TestNG > your run config > Common*.

However the easiest way is to move the test view to a side panel rather than the same area where the *console* is.